# SEGFAULT when using memcpy to copy from buffer to array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, memcpy

I have the following struct defined

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t type;
    uint16_t name_offset;
    uint32_t data_offset;
    uint32_t size;
}node;
```

`sizeof(node)` returns 12 bytes as expected.

```
node *nodes = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)*nodecount);
```

In my current test nodecount is 96 and the memory allocated for nodes is 1152 as expected.  (tested via _msize)

I want to memcpy from a buffer I have at offset 20 into this new nodes array (this is where I crash).  I have confirmed that 0x20(inclusive)-0x4A0(exclusive) is the correct structure for this array.

```
memcpy(nodes,buffer[0x20],sizeof(node)*nodecount)
```

Buffer looks like this

```
00000020: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 60
...
00000490: 00 00 00 88 00 00 06 89 02 15 DE 40
```

Comment: `0x20` - `32` in decimal.

Comment: Sorry misformatted offset is 32 (0x20)...forgot the 0x

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to use `memcpy` would be (from the description given)(*a buffer I have at offset 32 into this new nodes array*)

```
memcpy(nodes,buffer+32,sizeof(node)*nodecount);
```

or

```
memcpy(nodes,&buffer[0x20],sizeof(node)*nodecount);
```

Earlier you didn't pass the address, rather you passed the value itself. You made an attempt to access some memory location you are not supposed to leading to segmentation fault.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you!  Definitely an oversight.  I've used memcpy plenty of other times with buffer + offset.

Comment: @apmeyers1987 How come the compiler didn't warn about this?

Comment: @BjornA. Compiling without warnings :)

Comment: that is a bad bad idea

Comment: @VladP Who wants to live forever?

Comment: :)  yeah live dangerously and don't sell your code to anyone :)